# Does a simplex with equal altitudes have to be equilateral?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, simplex

Consider a simplex in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Assume that all its altitudes have the same length. Does it necessarily mean that the simplex is equilateral, i. e. all distances between its vertices are equal too?

Comment: Nice question. The term generally used for such a simplex is *regular* (rather than equilateral).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's obviously wrong. Indeed, we can get a 3-dimensional tetrahedron where edges are divisible into pairs, and each of them contains 2 non-intersecting edges with the same length. Then each facet of the tetrahedron has the same square $S$, and it easily follows from this that each altitude has a length equal to $\frac{3\cdot Volume}{S}$, but the tetrahedron isn't regular.